# How to anchor matchlist after searchpos?

Tags: regular-expression, matchlist

I'm trying to find words before the cursor using `searchpos`, then use `matchlist` to get the captures.  I can't find a reliable way to anchor the pattern for `matchlist`.  For example, if the cursor is positioned on `[cursor]`

```
" 3456789012345
" !!foobar !!foobaz [cursor]  !!foobat

let pat = '\%(!!\)\@<=fooba\(.\)'
let [l, c] = searchpos(pat, 'bWn')    " returns [2, 14]

echo 'pat1'
echo l c matchlist(getline(l), pat)                     | " bad
echo l c matchlist(getline(l), pat, c-3)                | " ok
echo l c matchlist(getline(l), '\%'.c.'c\%('.pat.'\)')  | " ok
```

`searchpos` finds the column 14, since the look-behind is not included in the match.  The first `matchlist` finds the wrong `fooba.`.  Thus, I need to anchor the pattern using the column number.  The second alternative is not an option because it would require me to know how many characters were zero-width'd.  The third one works great, until...

```
let pat = '!!\zsfooba\(.\)'
let [l, c] = searchpos(pat, 'bWn')    " also returns [2, 14]

echo 'pat2'
echo l c matchlist(getline(l), pat)                     | " bad
echo l c matchlist(getline(l), pat, c-3)                | " ok
echo l c matchlist(getline(l), '\%'.c.'c\%('.pat.'\)')  | " bad
```

Here, prepending the column number doesn't work because although `\zs` is zero-width, the stuff before it is not.

Note:

- I need a general-purpose solution since this is for a plugin and `pat` is supplied by the user.
- I can't simply replace `\zs` with `\%14c\zs`, because there may be alternations `\|` in the pattern.  For example `foo\%14c\zsbar\|foobaz` will allow `foobaz` in any position.
- This is not actually peculiar to `searchpos`- the same would be seen with e.g., the character index from `match`.
- Negative look-behinds in `pat` are possible.
- A perfect answer would include the possibility of `\ze`.

Comment: Sneakily changing the test cases after I answer! Cursor position is easy to workaround, though, I think? Going to have to think about negative lookbehind some more, though.

Comment: that is not so easily possible. Thinking about a multiline pattern, that will likely break

Comment: I'm not following your new note about it not being peculiar to `searchpos`. Could you add a new test case to demonstrate how it's failing with `match`? (Or just describe it more?) Similarly, a test case for `\ze` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that is that `searchpos` is searching backwards (from the position of the cursor) and `matchlist` is searching forwards (from the start of the line).

How about altering the way we call `matchlist` to search backwards too, via the time honoured technique of brute force?

```
let line1 = getline(l)
let line2 = getline(l)[c:]
let line1 = line1[:c-1]

" We want to ignore matches found *after* the position returned by 
" searchpos()
let boo = matchlist(line2, pat)

while len(line1) > 0
  let line2 = line1[-1:] . line2
  let line1 = line1[:-2]
  let yay = matchlist(line2, pat)
  if len(yay) > 0 && yay != boo
    echo l c yay
    break
  endif
endwhile
```

It's ugly and inefficient, and I have a feeling it might be possible to construct a complicated regular expression that breaks it, but it works for the test cases given.

Comment: Interested to see if you come up with anything using clever lookbehinds.  A while loop solution is what I will resort to if there's no more efficient way. 
  Note that I updated the example to make it clear there could be `fooba.` after the cursor position also.

Comment: No, I meant negative lookbehind will break this solution. I think it might be possible to workaround, though, although I'm not sure if alternations will flummox me, too. The cursor position thing should be easier to fix, I think.

Comment: @Mass I edited my answer to handle your question edit. I think I was mistaken about negative lookbehind, so I'm not aware of any cases that this answer fails on. Please let me know if you find any!